# Finding peak in a large data set with Python

Tags: python, arrays

I want to know if there is a way to eliminate points that are not close to the peak.

For example if I have a data set with 10 million points and the peak is around 5 million, how could I get rid of points that are nowhere near close to the peak so I can narrow down where my index point resides

Comment: Are you trying to find the largest value in an array?

Comment: yes in an array of 10 million points.

Comment: If using numpy you can use the max function. ` array.max()` Here's the documentation: https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.max.html?highlight=max#numpy.ndarray.max

Answer (score 0):

You need first to define what is the range of numbers that are close to the peak. Let's assume you specify a threshold number, so you can keep only the elements that are close to the peak with distance at most threshold by using  Numpy with condition. For example:

```
import numpy as np
data_size = 10000000
max_possible_peak = 5000000
data = np.random.rand(data_size) * max_possible_peak
threshold = 100
peak = max(data)
data_near = data[data > peak-threshold]
```

Comment: Will this work for an array? I started with an arange of (0,10_000_000,1_000_000) but im trying to get all the way down to step by 1 but eliminating some of the data helps  it run faster so i want to end with something like (4_999_999, 5_000_021,1)